# Color lookup table / Color manipulation / Color correction

Tags: openlayers

I want to manipulate the colors of a tile layer. I found three solutions, all not adequate.

**Solution 1:** I use an image layer (`ol.layer.Image`) that uses a raster source (`ol.source.Raster`) whose colors can be manipulated. See OpenLayers’ [Color Manipulation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/color-manipulation.html) example. Once the image is rendered, zooming in and out is smooth as the image’s pixels are not manipulated on every frame; the image is only resized. The downside is that while zooming out, the image becomes smaller until it no longer fills out the canvas. Only when zooming stops is it completely redrawn to fill out the canvas. This solution cannot be used because my users should always see all available map data, even while zooming out. The “zoom out, wait, fill canvas” cycle is too distracting.

**Solution 2:** Extending solution 1, I add a tile layer underneath the image layer so that the canvas is always filled with map data when zooming out. See OpenLayers’ [Shaded Relief](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/shaded-relief.html) example. The downside is that on zooming out, the area outside of the image layer shows the non-color-manipulated tile layer. This solution cannot be used because my users must not be aware of any color correction.

**Solution 3:** I use a tile layer and add an event listener to my `ol.Map` instance listening for the `postcompose` event. When this event fires, I manipulate the canvas context directly by reading the pixel colors, changing them and writing them back to the context. This works but is incredibly slow as `postcompose` fires on every frame and I have to manipulate all the canvas’s pixels anew.

**My questions:**

1. How can I efficiently manipulate the colors of a tile layer while avoiding the problems of solution 1 (background becomes visible when zooming out) and solution 2 (second layer doesn’t match first one)?
2. Does OpenLayers support color lookup tables?
3. Can a color profile be set?

Answer (score 1):

Check out ol-ext on github, they have a color filter extension that uses a tile layer in the example. As far as color profiles go, they have some predefined ones, like grayscale and sepia. You could probably did through their code and find the section to come up with your own.

> http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.colorize.html